# Why isn't my turtle keybinding responding?

Tags: python, module, turtle-graphics, key-bindings

I am in the process of modulating my code for a game that I wrote. When I modulated the player class, I add all the additional parameters/arguments so it can be separated. I kept the keybinding within the the main game module.

The keybinding code look like this

```
turtle.listen()
a=turtle.onkey(player.go_left(walls), "Left")
b=turtle.onkey(player.go_right(walls), "Right")
c=turtle.onkey(player.go_up(walls), "Up")
d=turtle.onkey(player.go_down(walls), "Down")
e=turtle.onkey(player.headright(missile,lives), "d")
f=turtle.onkey(player.headleft(missile,lives), "a")
g=turtle.onkey(player.headdown(missile,lives),"s")
h=turtle.onkey(player.headup(missile,lives),"w")
i=turtle.onkey(player.headright(missile,lives),"D")
j=turtle.onkey(player.headleft(missile,lives), "A")
k=turtle.onkey(player.headdown(missile,lives),"S")
l=turtle.onkey(player.headup(missile,lives),"W")
o=turtle.onkey(player.drink(info),"space")
m=turtle.onkey(player.fireball(missile2,info,lives),"z")
n=turtle.onkey(player.fireball(missile2,info,lives),"Z")
```

The game is running without error but the keys aren't responding to the action.

You can find the code in

https://github.com/Ninedeadeyes/7-Dungeons-Deep/tree/master

The keybinding code is in game(mod version)

All functions are within 'player.py'

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why are you capturing the return value from `onkey` in variables? It's always None? Why are you calling `onkey` and `listen` on `turtle` - usually, `onkey` is called on `screen`?

Comment: I was trying something but even if you remove the variables it doesn't make any difference. Both onkey and listen are turtle methods.. You might use something else with these methods but if you are using turtle library this should work.. It works when I wrote the game in one file but had to add additional augments due to modulating the code. If you can provide some feedback on what it should be so instead of turtle.onkey, I will be grateful

Comment: From reading a bit more, i think i can only add a function with no arguments for it to work 

https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey

Comment: hence why my original code works whilst when i separate the code and add augments, to the onkey function it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Since you didn't provide an example of the code of `player.go_left(walls)` etc., I assumed it returned the appropriate type (i.e. a callback function with no parameters) - but yes, that needs to be a function. If your question is essentially answered by that, either write a good answer and accept it, or close the question.

Comment: The correct answer will be to use a lambda code to get around the 'function with no parameters.. Case solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onkey function only allows a function with no arguments hence it is not possible to use functions with arguments hence why it doesn't work.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkey

But... If you use

turtle.onkey((lambda:player.go_left(walls)), "Left")

it will work because you are creating a function within a function which will express the output as if it had no arguments.